# Good Linux distribution for Macbook Air and VirtualBox

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, unix, virtualization, virtualbox

I have seen many Linux distributions tried to be used in Macbook Air, for instance. 
One custom made of Redhat Linux is one successful port in VirtualBox but it is not public. 
However, I would like to know how well other public Linux distributions work with Macbook Air in VirtualBox.

I am thinking these distros

- Fedora Linux (Torvalds may use but dislike Gnome3)
- Debian Linux (used by many of my Science friends)
- OpenSUSE (rejected by Torvalds)
- ...

Which Linux distributions have adequate support for Macbook Air and VirtualBox?

Comment: Personally I use Linux Mint 17.1 under VMware Fusion 7.1.1 on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) and it runs great.  Haven't tried it in VirtualBox however I have run other OSes under VB and they ran okay but not as nice as with VMware Fusion.  Don't get me wrong, VirtualBox for its price is a nice piece of software however I find its GUI compared to other Mac Applications somewhat unrefined and use it only when I can't run something under VMware Fusion or Parallels.  That said I see no reason you cannot use VirtualBox on your MacBook Air using any of the top Linux Distros.

Comment: @user3439894 The only reason I use VirtualBox is that it is free which is a requirement set in many research groups.

Comment: Is 'rejection' by Torvalds important?  There are reports that he reacts loudly to things he doesn't like at the time, but sometimes changes his mind later.      Look up what he said about HFS.

Comment: Any reason you're ruling out the BSDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu or Mint are the distros I'd recommend. They're both well-supported. Also, don't pay much attention to Torvalds. The man has an opinion on everything, and he isn't always right... I mean, he made the Linux kernel into a Monolithic kernel, and that has its issues.

Comment: Great catch - the Linux Mint! I wonder if there is configured Linux Mint for VirtualBox supported by the community.

Comment: Well, there are these images available if you need to save a bit of time: http://www.osboxes.org/linux-mint/ But really, any Linux distro I've ever tried works just fine in VirtualBox, installed the same way you'd install it on the bare metal.

Comment: @scottishwildcat Yes, I know the internet site. The problem is that the site does not seem to be supported by any Linux community. Say if I am wrong. I want community supported virtual images.